# JavaScript add HTML field value

Tags: javascript, addition

I know this is a very basic question but I am very basic with JavaScript.
I have a form which is attempting to duplicate a paper form.
It has six groups of inputs angler details 1, angler details 2 etc.
What I would like to do is add a value to a hidden field in each group if angler surname is not equal to something like

```
if ang:surname <> ""
ang:dollars = 75
else ang:dollars = 0
```

**My JS:**

```
<script>
    function getdollar() { 
        if(f.saveangler.checked == true) { 
            f.a1angler = "99"; 
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

I have tried a multitude of little scripts without success.
Can someone more knowledgeable than me (and that is nearly everyone here i guess) help out?

Thanks with optimism
John

Comment: Can you show us the real code please?

Comment: <script>          
           
 function getdollar() 
 {
  if(f.saveangler.checked == true) {
    f.a1angler = "99";
    
  }
}      
       </script>

Comment: Please add the code into the question as an edit.

Comment: Hi! Could you provide your HTML? Also could you provide the entire javascript code?

Comment: which language is you write in the first part?

Answer (score 0):

Though it's hard to know without seeing your exact HTML, you might try an approach like this...

Assuming you have fields in each form already like "a1surname"...

```
function addHiddenInput (surname) {
    var input = document.createElement("input");
    input.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    input.setAttribute("name", "dollars");
    input.setAttribute("value", f[surname] === '' ? "75" : "0");
    f.appendChild(input);
}
```

...then pass "a1surname" to the `addHiddenInput` function, e.g., perhaps within an onsubmit listener on each separate form...

```
<form onsubmit="addHiddenInput('a1surname');">
```

...or detect it based on info within the form.